What does residual tithi or Picham calendar system mean?
Trying to understand why some people are celebrating Vijayadashami on 12-Oct-2024 and some on 13-Oct-2024.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
